# HashSet doesnt allow duplicates but how to write logic for allowing duplicates

Tags: java

Consider the following program:

```
import java.util.*;

class SetDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set s=new HashSet();

        s.add("ajay");
        s.add(120);
        s.add("A");
        s.add(120);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

It outputs `[A,ajay,120]`, but I want the output to contain `120` 2 times.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: You know the answer, because a few hours ago you asked how to make a `List` without duplicates and everyone told you to use a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HashMap` for key, value pairs. Or even a List. Sets by design only contain unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

Write a list to add the values. It allows duplicates.

```
List s=new ArrayList(); 
s.add("ajay"); 
s.add(120);
 s.add("A");
 s.add(120); 
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: send me answer using set but not using list

Comment: set doesnt allow duplicates. You need to take help of some collections to keep track of duplicates eventhough you use set.